# Does next_ds behave correctly across daylight savings in timezone aware DAG?

Tags: airflow, dst

I am running a timezone-aware DAG (tz=Europe/London) with a schedule of `0 0 * * 1-5`.

In the run for Friday, `2020-03-27`, `next_ds` is set to `2020-03-29`. However, according to the schedule, I would have expected it to be `2020-03-30`.

The interval contains the daylight saving skip - is it possible that `next_ds` does not properly take this into account? Or is there a different explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I should have read the manual - on https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/timezone.html it says

> Airflow returns time zone aware datetimes in templates, but does not convert them to local time so they remain in UTC. It is left up to the DAG to handle this.

I am now solving this using jinja filters, defining

```
def local_ds(execution_date):
    return execution_date.in_timezone(local_tz).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

and then using `{{ execution_date | local_ds }}` inside the template.

I imagine this particularly bites people that work with `Europe/London` timezones, as midnight in local time is midnight in UTC in winter time, but in summertime it becomes 23:00 on the previous day in UTC, therefore changing the date.